# Grails asset-pipeline Shows wrong Build Path in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, grails, dependency-management

My problem is resolved but I don't understand why it wasn't working.
Using: Grails 2.4.2, Groovy 2.3.7, Java 1.7, Eclipse- Indigo

I set my project up, and in the assets folder under grails-app I placed my static assets.  I was also using twitter-bootstrap. The project would run, but nothing would be displayed from the assets folder.  I did a Grails clean and got build path errors.   in Eclipse  right clicking the project name and going to Java Build Path and under the source tab there were links such as:

projectName/.link_to_grails_plugins/cache-1.1.7/src/java
or
projectName/.link_to_grails_plugin/asset-pipeline-1.8.11/grails-app/controllers etc

I deleted my target directory, and deleted all the links that were errors inside the Source tab.  I restarted eclipse and refreshed, and voila it worked.  The links came back, looked exactly the same but were now good apparently.   I'm just not 100% sure why it worked though.  The assets were in the right place, and never moved.   Why did this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't parse BuildConfig.groovy or infer paths or dependencies - it gets all of that from Grails. You can force it to reconfigure the classpath by right-clicking on the project node in the tree on the left and selecting Grails Tools | Refresh Dependencies. That will cause Eclipse to run `grails compile --non-interactive --refresh-dependencies` and it gets classpath information from that.

When you restarted it must have determined that enough had been deleted that it needed to refresh itself, or it might just do that each time you restart.